# How to use Scan and Query in Single Table Architecture - DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have implemented a single table architecture in my project. I got some  problem about using DynamoDB Scan and Query Methods because In my db i got multiple Items about the different modules ex: login,register..etc. So the Key not same in each item. I'm only set the KeyType for identify the Item in yml. I don't know how to use the Scan and Query method in single table arch.

If i use scan method i got the entire item from database. Without any expression or condition *ex: FilterExpression, KeyConditionExpression*

```
my yaml file ex:
Resources:  
    TABLENAMEDynamoDBTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'      
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: TABLENAME  

var params = {
    TableName: 'TABLENAME'   
};
dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

Output: Item:[{...},...]

but if i use the expression or condition the error will be through. not only scan. same in query also

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'TABLENAME',
    Limit: 10, 
    FilterExpression:'#user =:val',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#user": "status",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":val": 'active'
    }
};
dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

I expected output

```
Item:[{status:'active',..},{status:'active',..},...]
```

but I got this error.

```
"message":"There were 7 validation
errors: InvalidParameterType: Expected params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':val'] to be a structure 
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '0' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':val']
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '1' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':val'] 
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '2' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':val'] 
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '3' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':val'] 
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '4' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':val'] 
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '5' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':val']... etc
```

So anyone can resolve this problem and explain about the single table architecture design, scan and query to use.

Comment: If you're using a single table table to store different types of items, I recommend you use a range key to store a type identifier. Additionally, you can define a GSI using the table's range key as the index's hash key and a arbitrary attribute as a range key. This will enable you to easily query all items of a certain type.

Comment: sorry for this delayed reply. I will try this. thanks